# Nesting a flat list

Tags: php, arrays, file, nested

I've spent almost all day trying to convert this flat list of category into a nested list, as it should be, since its a 5-level deep category list.

Here's an example:

```
$array = 
array (
  array (
    'CategoryID' => '001',
    'CategoryLevel' => '1',
    'CategoryName' => 'Category 1',
    'CategoryParentID' => '001'
  ),
  array (
    'CategoryID' => '002',
    'CategoryLevel' => '2',
    'CategoryName' => 'Category 2',
    'CategoryParentID' => '001'
  ),
  array (
    'CategoryID' => '003',
    'CategoryLevel' => '3',
    'CategoryName' => 'Category 3',
    'CategoryParentID' => '002'
  ),
  array (
    'CategoryID' => '004',
    'CategoryLevel' => '4',
    'CategoryName' => 'Category 4',
    'CategoryParentID' => '003'
  ),
  array (
    'CategoryID' => '005',
    'CategoryLevel' => '5',
    'CategoryName' => 'Category 5',
    'CategoryParentID' => '004'
  )
);
```

I need to know how I should change this array so I could then convert it in a text file with each sub-category intended by a `tab`.

[Here's](http://gist.github.com/3zzy/70007216ffe92cbc7992) what I've been doing, and [here's](http://goo.gl/qHWHMj) the actual array that I'm working on.

```
$categories = array();
foreach ($array['CategoryArray']['Category'] as $category) {
  //echo print_r($category,1);
  echo 'category parent ID: '.$category['CategoryParentID']."\n";
  $array_search = recursive_array_search($category['CategoryParentID'], $categories);
  echo 'Array search: '.$array_search."\n";
  $index = isset($array_search) ? $array_search : false;
  echo 'index: '.print_r($index)."\n";
  if ($index) {
      //echo "\n\n=================".
      $category['CategoryID'].
      ' - '.
      $category['CategoryName'].
      ' (PARENT: '. $category['CategoryParentID'].
      ') =================';
      $value = eval('$categories'.$index);
      $value[$category['CategoryID']] = $category['CategoryName'];
  }
  else {
    //echo "\n\n=================".$category['CategoryID'].' - '.$category['CategoryName'].'=================';
    $categories[$category['CategoryParentID']][$category['CategoryID']] = $category['CategoryName'];
  }
}
```

Comment: A good start would be to show us what you've already tried, explain why it didn't work, and show a sample desired output.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/3zzy/70007216ffe92cbc7992 <- this is what I did, but didn't post the whole script because no one would go through it all.

Comment: And here's the actual array that is returned: http://goo.gl/qHWHMj

Comment: Put the relevant parts of the code in the question

Comment: Ok, just did, but I've seen the more complicated the question gets, less likely people are to respond so I made it simple.

Comment: c'mon let's give a 14k+ member the benefit of the doubt ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problematic part is (re-?)constructing the hierarchie but once you have that indenting the output isn't a problem.
Haven't tested it (with edge cases) - but I'm fairly confident....

```
<?php
$h = foo( getData() ) ;
var_export($h);

/* the assumption here is:
    when iterating $src the parent elements are always iterated before their respective child elements
    reverse the array and the opposite is true: the child element will always be iterated first
    -> ALL child elements are "waiting" for their respective parent element to "collect" them
    <-> when the parent element is iterated all its children have already been iterated

    Once an element is iterated it therefore
      - looks for its (previously iterated and stored) childnodes
      - "registers" itself in that storage array
        - unless its a root element (parentid==ownid), in which case it's registered as root element
*/
function foo(array $src) {
    $src = array_reverse($src);
    $toBeCollected = array(); // all the children waiting for their parents
    $retval = array();  // array of root elements

    foreach( $src as $e ) {
        // first we collect the children (if there are any)
        if ( isset($toBeCollected[ $e['CategoryID'] ]) ) {
            $e['childnodes'] = $toBeCollected[ $e['CategoryID'] ];
            unset($toBeCollected[ $e['CategoryID'] ]);
        }

        if ( $e['CategoryID']===$e['CategoryParentID'] ) {
            // it's a root element
            $retval[ $e['CategoryID'] ] = $e;
        }
        else {
            setEntry($toBeCollected, $e['CategoryParentID'], $e);
        }
    }

    return $retval;
}


function setEntry(array &$target, $key, $value) {
    if ( isset($target[$key]) ) {
        $target[$key][] = $value;
    }
    else {
        $target[$key] = array($value);
    }
}


function getData() {
    return array (
      array (
        'CategoryID' => '001',
        'CategoryLevel' => '1',
        'CategoryName' => 'Category 1',
        'CategoryParentID' => '001'
      ),
      array (
        'CategoryID' => '002',
        'CategoryLevel' => '2',
        'CategoryName' => 'Category 2',
        'CategoryParentID' => '001'
      ),
      array (
        'CategoryID' => '003',
        'CategoryLevel' => '3',
        'CategoryName' => 'Category 3',
        'CategoryParentID' => '002'
      ),
      array (
        'CategoryID' => '004',
        'CategoryLevel' => '4',
        'CategoryName' => 'Category 4',
        'CategoryParentID' => '003'
      ),
      array (
        'CategoryID' => '005',
        'CategoryLevel' => '5',
        'CategoryName' => 'Category 5',
        'CategoryParentID' => '004'
      ),
      array (
        'CategoryID' => '006',
        'CategoryLevel' => '2',
        'CategoryName' => 'Category 6',
        'CategoryParentID' => '001'
      )
    );
}
```

edit: same thing without the temporary kindergarden

```
<?php
$h = foo( getData() ) ;
var_export($h);

/* the assumption here is:
    when iterating $src the parent elements are always iterated before their respective child elements
    reverse the array and the opposite is true: the child element will always be iterated first
    -> ALL child elements are "waiting" for their respective parent element to "collect" them
    <-> when the parent element is iterated all its children have already been iterated

    Once an element is iterated it therefore
      looks for its (previously iterated and stored) childnodes
        "registers" itself in that storage array
          unless its a root element (parentid==ownid), in which case it's registered as root element
*/
function foo(array $src) {
    $src = array_reverse($src);
    $nodes = array();

    foreach( $src as $e ) {
        // if there were child nodes "they" already created an entry in $nodes for this/current node
        if ( isset($nodes[$e['CategoryID']]) ) {
            // in this case the current node just "imports" the childnodes
            $e['childnodes'] = $nodes[$e['CategoryID']]['childnodes'];
            // "imports" means: node is moved, means: unset() on previous location
            unset($nodes[$e['CategoryID']]);
        }

        // now we check if the current node has a parent or is a root
        if ( $e['CategoryID']===$e['CategoryParentID'] ) {
            // it's a root -> gets stored under its own id
            $nodes[ $e['CategoryID'] ] = $e;
        }
        // it's a childnode -> create/append to stub for parent
        else  if ( isset($nodes[ $e['CategoryParentID'] ]) ) {
            // there already was another child -> append to stub
            $nodes[ $e['CategoryParentID'] ]['childnodes'][] = $e;
        }
        else {
            // first child visited -> create stub
            $nodes[ $e['CategoryParentID'] ] = array('childnodes' =>array($e));
        }
    }   
    return $nodes;
}



function getData() {
    return array (
      array (
        'CategoryID' => '001',
        'CategoryLevel' => '1',
        'CategoryName' => 'Category 1',
        'CategoryParentID' => '001'
      ),
      array (
        'CategoryID' => '002',
        'CategoryLevel' => '2',
        'CategoryName' => 'Category 2',
        'CategoryParentID' => '001'
      ),
      array (
        'CategoryID' => '003',
        'CategoryLevel' => '3',
        'CategoryName' => 'Category 3',
        'CategoryParentID' => '002'
      ),
      array (
        'CategoryID' => '004',
        'CategoryLevel' => '4',
        'CategoryName' => 'Category 4',
        'CategoryParentID' => '003'
      ),
      array (
        'CategoryID' => '005',
        'CategoryLevel' => '5',
        'CategoryName' => 'Category 5',
        'CategoryParentID' => '004'
      ),
      array (
        'CategoryID' => '006',
        'CategoryLevel' => '2',
        'CategoryName' => 'Category 6',
        'CategoryParentID' => '001'
      )
    );
}
```

Comment: on second thought .... why have separate storage and root arrays? Anyway, there's always room for optimization.

Comment: Whoa, incredible! Thanks heaps!